# JS - revert monkey patched / overridden function to native code

Tags: javascript, overriding, native

I came across window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send that had been monkey patched / overridden by a third-party using their own version of the function which intercepted the calls from our page.  As a first party, is there any way for me to remove the patching and revert the functionality to native code?

Comment: Without knowing all the side effects. I think something like this could work: `window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe')).contentWindow.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;`

Comment: Another alternative could be to store the function in a variable before it has a chance to bind and replace it with the original if/when necessary (or instead use the function `call` method wherever needed).

Comment: Using `defineProperty` to set the method on the prototype at the beginning can actually prevent a successful binding to begin with.

Comment: Thought I'd add more context as it's been down voted. Would prefer if people comment as to why when they downvote! I came across a third-party that was intercepting all communications and tracking all the resources used on a page. The way it was being done is by monkey patching / overriding native code and binding to proxy methods. Is there any way as a first party for me to remove these bindings at runtime and revert it to native code?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any way to guarantee that an arbitrary script which replaces something in the global scope won't effectively block any kind of reversal of such a change. The best fix would probably be to prevent the offending code from running to begin with. If you're still satisfied with your suggested course of action then I would recommend one of the following solutions (try them in order):

Solution #1 - Use `Object.defineProperty` in an attempt to prevent future changes:

```
// have this line execute before the offending script does
Object.defineProperty(XMLHttpRequest.prototype, 'send', {
    value: XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send,
    writable: false
    });
```

Solution #2 - Store a reference to the function and attempt to replace it later:

```
// have this line execute before the offending script does
const XMLHTTPRequest_send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;

// have this line execute after
// Object.defineProperty is probably needed if the first solution doesn't work
Object.defineProperty(XMLHttpRequest.prototype, 'send', {
    value: XMLHTTPRequest_send
    });
```

This will not guarantee that the other script won't be ready to change things back again.